# Sender for didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to find out who is calling didSelectRowAtIndexPathv (View or UIImage) so I can choose between two different segues, however I can't find any reference to the sender (caller of the function) or how to do it any other way.

I was able to make it work using accessory detail but it just look terrible!

Comment: What do you mean 'the sender'?  You know the tableview that the row is in and you know the index path.  From the tableview you can find the containing view if that is what you need.

Comment: I know the cell and the index path of the cell, but I want to know if was the UIView or the UIImage from that cell that send it.

Comment: It doesn't work like that - the cell does not distinguish what was tapped. You would need to add your own buttons to get that information

Comment: You will need to add your own touch handling to get this information - add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the cell class